# Dynamic Gitlab CI/CD for Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a gitlab-ci.yaml file that looks like this

```
stages:
  - generate_ci
  - trigger_ci

variables:
  AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.aws
  AWS_CREDENTIALS:
    value: ""
    description: "Insert Short-term credentials from AWS SSO"
  AWS_PROFILE: 
    value: "AWS_Profile"
    description: "Replace it if needed"

before_script:
   - cp $AWS_CREDENTIALS ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.aws

generate_ci:
  stage: generate_ci
  image: alpine:latest
  extends:
    - .commit_common
  script: 
    - source scripts/build_artifacts.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - generated_ci.gitlab-ci.yml
  when: manual

trigger_ci:
  stage: trigger_ci
  extends:
    - .commit_common
  needs:
    - generate_ci
  variables:
    AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE: "$AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE"
    AWS_CREDENTIALS: "$AWS_CREDENTIALS"
    AWS_PROFILE: "$AWS_PROFILE"
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: generated_ci.gitlab-ci.yml
        job: generate_ci
    strategy: depend
  when: manual
```

the file build_artifacts.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get list of dirrectories that has main.tf
directories=$(find . -maxdepth 2 -name "main.tf" -exec dirname {} \;)

cat > generated_ci.gitlab-ci.yml <<- EOF

image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/stable:latest

before_script:
    - mkdir \${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.aws
    - echo \$AWS_CREDENTIALS > \${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.aws/credentials

.tf-dynamic-init-plan:
  stage: build
  script:  
    - cd \${TF_ROOT}
    - gitlab-terraform init
    - gitlab-terraform validate
    - gitlab-terraform plan
    - gitlab-terraform plan-json
  artifacts:
    name: plan
    expire_in: 3 week
    paths:
      - \${TF_ROOT}/plan.cache
    reports:
      terraform: \${TF_ROOT}/plan.json
  when: always
EOF


for dir in $directories; do
    project=$(basename "$dir")  
    echo "Found main.tf in $dir"
    cat >> generated_ci.gitlab-ci.yml <<- EOF

Init-plan-$project:
  variables:
    TF_ROOT: \${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/$project
    TF_STATE_NAME: $project
  extends:
    - .tf-dynamic-init-plan

EOF
done

echo "Done."
```

This CI must create a dynamic pipeline for every main.tf that founded in the repo, but it looks like I'm not passing the accesses to the dynamic pipeline correctly. If I did everything the standard way, everything works fine

```
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.
╷
│ Error: configuring Terraform AWS Provider: failed to get shared config profile, AWS_Profile
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on provider.tf line 1, in provider "aws":
│    1: provider "aws" {
│ 
╵
```

I took this project as an example https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/project-templates/jsonnet/-/pipelines/560894622
Unfortunately, it does not show how you can add credentials